# Unable to add / update restaurant reviews on freecodecamp's "Restaurant reviews" project course

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am doing the new MERN Stack Course of restaurant reviews ([video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrHNSanmqQ4)).

Till now, I haven’t made it serverless yet.

When trying to add a review (logged in), and then click on submit, it shows that it was successful, however, it doesn’t show up on the frontend. When checked in the collections in MongoDB, under the reviews, it shows:

```
_id: ObjectId('635102f6f99e930c65921e72')
name:null,
user_id:null
date:2022-10-20T08:12:38.661+00:00
text:null,
restaurant_id:ObjectId('635102f6f99e930c65921e71')
```

Also, I can’t update an existing review (logged in as that user). It throws the following error in the console:

```
AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 500
"name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: {…}, status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48712:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47452:66)"[[Prototype]]: Error
```

What can be the fix for this? github repo: https://github.com/sohamdata/restaurant-reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug in Beau Carnes's code! In the frontend app, the helper file (http-common.js) has a typo error in the axios.create() method. Below the baseURL, headers is specified as "Content-type": instead of "**Content-Type**": Therefore the backend server is unable to resolve the body type (which should be JSON) of the data sent from the frontend app. Specifying headers : { "Content-Type": "application/json" } worked in my case. I wonder how Beau go his code working with that typo error.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that solved it. I think in Beau's case the formatters auto-corrected it.